# Regex to find URL including those that simply start with // (Protocol-relative URLs)

Tags: regex, url

This Regex finds URLs that begin with `http` and `https`

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

I am trying to figure out how to modify this to including those URLs which omit the `http` or `https` part. I understand that these are called '[Protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl)'

example: `//example.com` and not `http://example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the protocol part optional:

```
(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

By the way I assume you really wanted `example.com` and not `//example.com` (since no one writes a URL that way).

Comment: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/ it looks like it no longer in use for security reasons, but for my purposes I want to be able to capture urls that are still in this format

Comment: I see. I've made both the protocol and `//` optional then.